# Qual a melhor maneira de mostrar a simulação QuickSort Externo

Tags: java, swing, classificação, quicksort

Eu tenho que fazer um **simulador do quickSort externo**, mostrando por exemplo o passo a passo do mesmo.

**Mostrando modificações nas variáveis** limite inferior, limite superior, o vetor principal, o vetor da area(seria o espaço disponível na memória para ordenar o arquivo), escrita superior, escrita inferior, leitura inferior, leitura superior.

**Eu já fiz** o algoritmo do quickSort e o algoritmo da interface gráfica mostrando apenas o final da ordenação.

**Dúvida** qual a melhor forma de mostrar isso na interface gráfica e como fazer, alguma ideia? Não precisa fazer pra mim, apenas sugerir uma maneira simples para fazer, já que é a primeira vez que mexo com GUI. Vou postar a classe do quickSort e da interface.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package quicksortexterno;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class Quick {

    private int i, j;
    private List<Integer> vetorArquivo = new ArrayList<>();

    public Quick() {

    }

    public void addValor(int valor) {
        vetorArquivo.add(valor);
    }

    public String inicia() {
        quickSort(0, vetorArquivo.size() - 1);
        return vetorArquivo.toString();
    }

    public void particao(int esq, int dir) {

        int limiteSup;
        int limiteInf;
        List<Integer> area = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean teste = true;
        limiteInf = -100000000;
        limiteSup = 100000000;
        int escritaInf;
        int escritaSup;
        int leituraSup;
        int Li;
        int aux;
        Li = escritaInf = esq;
        leituraSup = escritaSup = dir;
        i = esq - 1;
        j = dir + 1;

        while (leituraSup >= Li) {
            if (area.size() < 2) {
                if (teste) {
                    area.add(vetorArquivo.get(leituraSup));
                    Collections.sort(area);

                    leituraSup--;
                    teste = false;
                } else {
                    area.add(vetorArquivo.get(Li));
                    Collections.sort(area);
                    Li++;
                    teste = true;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (leituraSup == escritaSup) {
                aux = vetorArquivo.get(leituraSup);
                leituraSup--;
                teste = false;
            } else {
                if (Li == escritaInf) {
                    aux = vetorArquivo.get(Li);
                    Li++;
                    teste = true;
                } else {
                    if (teste) {
                        aux = vetorArquivo.get(leituraSup);
                        leituraSup--;
                        teste = false;
                    } else {
                        aux = vetorArquivo.get(Li);
                        Li++;
                        teste = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (aux > limiteSup) {
                j = escritaSup;
                vetorArquivo.remove(escritaSup);
                vetorArquivo.add(escritaSup, aux);
                escritaSup--;
                continue;
            }
            if (aux < limiteInf) {
                i = escritaInf;
                vetorArquivo.remove(escritaInf);
                vetorArquivo.add(escritaInf, aux);
                escritaInf++;
                continue;
            }
            area.add(aux);
            Collections.sort(area);
            if (escritaInf - esq < dir - escritaSup) {
                vetorArquivo.remove(escritaInf);
                vetorArquivo.add(escritaInf, area.get(0));
                escritaInf++;
                limiteInf = area.get(0);
                area.remove(0);
            } else {
                vetorArquivo.remove(escritaSup);
                vetorArquivo.add(escritaSup, area.get(area.size() - 1));
                escritaSup--;
                limiteSup = area.get(area.size() - 1);
                area.remove(area.size() - 1);
            }
        }
        int k = 0;
        while (escritaInf <= escritaSup) {
            vetorArquivo.remove(escritaInf);
            vetorArquivo.add(escritaInf, area.get(k));
            k++;
            escritaInf++;
        }
        System.out.println(vetorArquivo.toString());
    }

    public void quickSort(int esq, int dir) {
        if (dir - esq >= 1) {
            particao(esq, dir);
            if (i - esq < dir - j) {
                quickSort(esq, i);
                quickSort(j, dir);
            } else {
                quickSort(j, dir);
                quickSort(esq, i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

-

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package quicksortexterno;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Janela extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Quick quick = new Quick();
    ArrayList<Integer> vetorAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    /**
     * Creates new form Janela
     */
    public Janela() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        quickSortButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        adicionar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        valor = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        labelAdd = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        label = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Simulador Quick Sort Externo");

        quickSortButton.setText("QuickSort");
        quickSortButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                quickSortButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        adicionar.setText("Adicionar");
        adicionar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                adicionarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        labelAdd.setText("   ");

        label.setText("    ");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(adicionar)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(valor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(labelAdd)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 655, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(quickSortButton)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(label)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(adicionar)
                    .addComponent(quickSortButton)
                    .addComponent(valor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(labelAdd))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(label)
                .addContainerGap(160, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        



    private void adicionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        quick.addValor(parseInt(valor.getText()));
        vetorAdd.add(parseInt(valor.getText()));

        labelAdd.setText(vetorAdd.toString());
        valor.setText("");
    }                                         

    private void quickSortButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String s = quick.inicia();
        label.setText(s);
    }                                               

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Janela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Janela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Janela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Janela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Janela().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton adicionar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel label;
    private javax.swing.JLabel labelAdd;
    private javax.swing.JButton quickSortButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField valor;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: formatar melhor como?

Comment: Dessa forma ficou bom?

Comment: Eu acho que é muito complicado dizer o que é melhor, depende de muitas coisas além do que foi perguntado, Veja como alguns fizeram: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ | http://sorting.at/ | http://panthema.net/2013/sound-of-sorting/